# Need help in manipulating string variable

Tags: string, shell, unix

I have written a shell script to do some processing and have to manipulate a variable. Basically, the variable is like this --

```
vaa="set policy:set cli"
```

My purpose is to split it into two variables based on the position of ":". To get the right end, I am doing this --

```
vaa1=${vaa#*:}
echo ${vaa1}   //this prints "set cli" which I want
```

However, I am not able to get the left part of the string  "set policy". I tried doing this --

```
vaa2=${vaa%*:}
```

But it didn't work and I am getting the whole string--"set policy:set cli". Any ideas on how to get the left part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter your pattern

```
echo ${vaa#*:}  
# from the beginning of the string, 
# delete anything up to and including the first :

echo ${vaa%:*}  
# from the end of the string, 
# delete the last : and anything after it
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
vaa2=${vaa%:*}
echo ${vaa2}
```

Comment: In bourne-type shells, you cannot have spaces around the "="

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it (bash)

```
$ vaa="set policy:set cli"
$ IFS=":"
$ set -- $vaa
$ echo $1
set policy
$ echo $2
set cli
```

or read into an array

```
$ IFS=":"
$ read -a array <<< "$vaa"
$ echo "${array[0]}"
set policy
$ echo "${array[1]}"
set cli
```